# Contact 7 Form not working to my email?

Tags: html, wordpress, email, contacts

I have latest contact 7 form installed. It will not send any messages to my email I'm not sure what's going on. It's not going to spam either just nothing happens. I'm not sure how to fix it. Please could anyone help me with this?

Comment: And have you tried to send an e-mail by function mail() or wp_mail()?

Answer (score 0):

Showing the green border message means that the PHP function for sending the mail has certainly completed successfully. So if you can’t receive the mail, it’s highly possible that the mail has been kidnapped or killed after that.

[image]

If you can check the log of your mail server, it could give you some clues. Spam filter often causes this kind of problem.